# Reading plot output without saving it as a file

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

Currently, I save the plotted output as below:

```
ImageName='MyGraph.jpg'    
myfig=df.plot(kind='bar')
img=myfig.get_figure()
img.savefig(ImageName)
```

And then read it with:

```
savedimage=cv2.imread(ImageName)
```

I want to skip the saving of the figure into an image and instead read the figure directly, something like this:

```
myfig=df.plot(kind='bar')
img=myfig.get_figure()
savedimage=cv2.imread(img)
```

This is not working, probably because `imread()` expects a file. Is there a way to do this? Should I be using a different method, if so what?

I want to do this as I do not need the physical copy of the image and I tend to believe that the i/o caused by this action could have a performance impact hence want to skip the file saving process. Is this possible?

Comment: What is `cv2` and `df`?

Comment: You can save to a bytesio in memory file.

Comment: @JodyKlymak: Wouldn't that require you to write to disk first? Do you happen to have a code snippet that will help me understand better?

Comment: @AmosEgel cv2 = OpenCV... df = Pandas DataFrame

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#buffered-streams

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fig.canvas.tostring_rgb()` and `np.fromstring` to extract the pixel values:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)

# need to draw first
fig.canvas.draw()
width, height = fig.canvas.get_width_height()

img = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), 
                    dtype=np.uint8
                   ).reshape(height, width,-1)  # also need to reshape

img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.RGB2BGR)
```

Comment: Does not seem to be working. Am getting the error AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasAgg' object has no attribute 'renderer'